# Why am I getting a mass of errors in my nested || statement?

Tags: mql4

Right, why am I getting a mass of errors in my nested `||` operator when there is no reason behind this?

Below is the code and the screenshot.

Thank you.

[Error Log Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDkku.png)

```html
if(BarTime != Time[0])
 
 {
 
  if(hammerHeadClose < hammerHeadOpen){
  
     if (bearHammerHead >= Transform(candleBodyLength,2))
     if (bearHammerHandle!=0 && (bearHammerHead / bearHammerHandle) <= hammerHandlePct)
     if (bullRetracementCandle!=0 && (bearHammerHead / bullRetracementCandle) <= hammerHeadPct)
  
  }
 
  else if (hammerHeadClose > hammerHeadOpen){
 
     if (bearHammerHead >= Transform(candleBodyLength,2))
     if (bearHammerHandle!=0 && (bearHammerHead / bearHammerHandle) <= hammerHandlePct)
     if (bullRetracementCandle!=0 && (bearHammerHead / bullRetracementCandle) <= hammerHeadPct)
 
  }
 
  if (bearHammerHead >= Transform(candleBodyLength,2))
  if (bearHammerHandle!=0 && (bearHammerHead / bearHammerHandle) <= hammerHandlePct)
  if (bullRetracementCandle!=0 && (bearHammerHead / bullRetracementCandle) <= hammerHeadPct)
  if (bullRetracementCandle!=0 && (initialTrendBearCandle / bullRetracementCandle) <= retracePercentage)
  if (bullRetracementCandle >= Transform(candleBodyLength,2))
  if (iMA(NULL,0,Period_TrendFast,0, AM_TrendFast,PRICE_CLOSE,1) < iMA(NULL,0,Period_TrendSlow,0,AM_TrendSlow,PRICE_CLOSE,1))
  if (iMA(NULL,0,Period_MomentumFast,0,AM_MomentumFast,PRICE_CLOSE,1) < iMA(NULL,0,Period_MomentumSlow,0,AM_MomentumSlow,PRICE_CLOSE,1))
  if (NewBar)
  if (spread <= MaxSpread)
  if (hourOfDay >= startingHour && hourOfDay < endingHour)
  if (OrdersTotal()== 0) { 

  OrderSend(....);

 }
}
```

Comment: You can not have nested `if()` statements within parenthesis `()`, they should properly be in brackets `{}`. If you share your full code it may be easier to provide assistance.

Comment: @PaulB Much appreciated, inserted the full code.

Comment: @PaulB I'm not going to lie, I am getting absolutely fuming with this right now, I have been coding for years and I have never had error after error after error after error after error after error.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to know what you are trying to achieve with the code posted. Generally, `if` statements use the following rules:

```
if(Condition)               // Header of the operator and condition
{
   Block 1 of operators     // If the condition is true, then..
   composing body 1         //..the operators composing body 1 are executed
}
```

Your code has lots of conditions without anything to execute. For example:

```
if(hammerHeadClose < hammerHeadOpen)
{
   if(bearHammerHead >= Transform(candleBodyLength,2))
   if(bearHammerHandle!=0 && (bearHammerHead / bearHammerHandle) <= hammerHandlePct)
   if(bullRetracementCandle!=0 && (bearHammerHead / bullRetracementCandle) <= hammerHeadPct)
}
```

This code does not actually do anything. You have nested `if` statements, but your final `if` statement needs to execute something, like so:

```
if(hammerHeadClose < hammerHeadOpen)
{
   if(bearHammerHead >= Transform(candleBodyLength,2))
   if(bearHammerHandle!=0 && (bearHammerHead / bearHammerHandle) <= hammerHandlePct)
   if(bullRetracementCandle!=0 && (bearHammerHead / bullRetracementCandle) <= hammerHeadPct)
   { /* Code to execute if previous 3 if statements conditions are met */ }
}
```

Your final block of 11 nested `if` statement would result in `OrderSend()` if all conditions were true, it is your first set of `if-else` which do not make sense. Hopefully this explanation will help.